# Import large data by using load data infile via PHP

Tags: dynamic, filepath, load-data-infile

After 20 hours of research as mentioned above, I came out 4 queries to load the large data into DB, however, it get errors "Query execute failed: ERRNO: ()" and there isn't any data were being insert into selected table. What has it went wrong, did I missed out something?

Below here is the file data
file.txt
V0012,aptext1,aptext2,aptext3,aptext6,apDesc2,apDesc3,USER0031

$temp_table_query = "CREATE TABLE `temp_inventoryList`(generated_id varchar(60) NOT NULL, "
."app_text1 varchar(60) NOT NULL, app_text2 varchar(60) NOT NULL, app_text6 varchar(60) NOT NULL, "
."app_desc2 varchar(500) NOT NULL, app_desc3 varchar(500) NOT NULL, created_by varchar(50) NOT NULL ); ";

```
         if (!($temp_table_stmt = $conn->query[$temp_table_query])) {
                echo "\nQuery execute failed: ERRNO: (" . $conn->error . ") " . $conn->error;
        }
        
        $load_data_query = " LOAD DATA INFILE " .'"upload/docs/file.txt"'." INTO TABLE `temp_inventoryList` "
                           ."FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' "
                           ."LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' "
                           ."(generated_id,app_text1, app_text2, app_text6,app_desc2,app_desc3,created_by)"
                           ."SET created_date=NOW(), app_display='Y'; ";
        
        if (!($load_data_stmt = $conn->query[$load_data_query])) {
                echo "\nQuery execute failed: ERRNO: (" . $conn->error . ") " . $conn->error;
        }
        
        $insert_query = " INSERT INTO `app_product` VALUES(generated_id,app_text1, app_text2, app_text6,app_desc2,app_desc3, created_by, created_date, app_display) "
                        ." SELECT generated_id, app_text1, app_text2, app_text6, app_desc2, app_desc3, created_by, created_date, app_display "
                        ." FROM `temp_inventoryList`; ";
        
        if (!($insert_stmt = $conn->query[$insert_query])) {
                echo "\nQuery execute failed: ERRNO: (" . $conn->error . ") " . $conn->error;
        }

        $drop_temp_query = " TRUNCATE TABLE `temp_inventoryList`;";
        
        if (!($drop_temp_stmt = $conn->query[$drop_temp_query])) {
                echo "\nQuery execute failed: ERRNO: (" . $conn->error . ") " . $conn->error;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL on LOAD DATA INFILE DO NOT work on web shared hosting therefore I changed my approached.